# Training linear Regression

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to run gradient descent algorithm in python. I got the algorithm to work when I split the data into columns. X being the features(independent) and y being the target.I want to modify my code so that it takes in training data (X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test).I do not know how to do this.

def grad(theta, alpha, X, y):

```
theta1 = np.matrix(np.zeros(theta.shape))
hypothesis = (X * theta.T)
error = hypothesis - y
for j in range(theta.shape[1]):
    temp = np.multiply(error, X[:,j])
    theta1[0,j] = theta[0,j] - ((alpha / len(X)) * np.sum(temp))

return theta1
```

gradientDecentMatP(theta, alpha, X, y)

Comment: if you need all the code let me know